# JBPM - Why task instances moved to Exited status?

Tags: jbpm

We are using JBPM 7.59.0.  Suddenly, all the pending task instances have moved to 'Exited' status altogether. I can see that, this happened at the same time for all the instances.

I have checked JBPM documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMTaskService.html). It is showing the Exited task status in the figure, but there is no details.

What could be the reason for all tasks suddenly moving to Exited status?

Answer (score 0):

The task status Exited is set if the parent application needs to end prematurely before the invoked human task has been completed. This is a 'negative outcome'.